# How can I know the minimum due credit card payment and date for an ANZ Visa card?

Tags: credit-card, australia, online-banking, visa

I have a Visa credit card from the ANZ bank in Australia. I'm currently overseas so cannot visit a branch and would like to avoid international phonecalls so I'm using only Internet banking and email.

I can't seem to find in ANZ online banking, or in anything they email me, the details of the credit card payments I need to make.

I assume there is a minimum amount I must pay by a certain date once per month.

Where can I find this information in ANZ online banking, in their emails to me, or in their online help.

I've tried looking through their help pages, Googling, and sending a "SecureMail", but have not yet found an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck, I have an ANZ credit card as well.

I have just checked my paper statement with online, and was able to find a matching online statement in less than a minute.

You simply click on your credit card account from the list of accounts. Under **Date Range** it will have the **Current incomplete statement period**. You simply click on the down arrow and select the last complete date range ending sometime in late April (depending on your credit card cycle). You then press on **View** next to the drop down box.

This should provide you with a list of purchases and payment/credits for that period, followed by a line with your **Credit Limit**, **Available Funds** and **Closing Balance**. The line below that then shows your **Due Date**, and **Overdue/Overlimit**, the **Minimum Payment** and **Amount Due Now**

If you are after paying only the minimum amount then you pay this amount by the due date (you will be charged interest if you only pay this amount). If, on the otherhand, you wish to avoid paying any interest then you need to pay the full Closing Balance before the due date.

You should also be able to get electronic statements sent to your email address.

Comment: Hmm I don't get this "line below that then shows your Due Date, and Overdue/Overlimit, the Minimum Payment and Amount Due Now". I guess that since I only started using it in the last two to three weeks that I don't even have a payment due yet, even though my last statement was yesterday since it was the first of the month.

Comment: My last statement went from the 25/03/14 to 27/04/14, with the due date on the 22/05/14. And yes for an incomplete payment period it won't have the second line, it will just have the first line with your Credit Limit, Available Funds and Closing Balance.